# How to copy a few files with different extensions using C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, copy-paste

Currently, I'm only able to copy and paste one file based on extension .jpg. However, for safety purposes, I'll need to ensure that .jpeg, .JPG & .JPEG gets copied and pasted as well.

Here is my code to paste one file with extension .jpg:

```
CFileStatus status;
CString strFileName = _T("Test2.jpg");
CString strFilePath = m_strImagePath + _T("\\") + strFileName;                      
CString strCopyPath = m_strCopyPath + _T("\\") + strFileName;
if(CFile::GetStatus(strFilePath, status))
{
    CopyFile(strFilePath, strCopyPath, FALSE);
}
```

So if given the example, where the folder I'm copying from looks like this:

[image]

Regardless of what name of the file is, as long it has these four extensions **(.jpg,.jpeg,.JPG,.JPEG)**, it should be copy and pasted.

So, how do I specify 4 different extensions? Is there a regex to do it or additional symbols to add? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's absolutely unclear what you are trying to do. You have "Test2.jpg" in your code and want to copy "Test3.jpg"?  You pass a variable strRecipe that is never declared or initialized? You call a function IsRecipeImageList what is not defined. Could you please provide a complete minimal working example? And what do you want to to with your code?

Comment: I've taken out the extra function on strRecipe. The Test2 is just an example of how I would copy one file. I've stated regardless of what name the file is, I need to copy them as long they fulfill these 4 extensions.

Comment: You probably want to search for files. `<filesystem>` is still experimental in VC, I think. It looks like you are using MFC: use `CFileFind`.

Comment: @ZDF I did use CFileFind to find all the files. With a couple of if statements, I got to sort out the files with extensions that I want. So, I'm good for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo about how to find a file with a special extension in a folder:

```
#include"pch.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<io.h>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include <Windows.h>

int get_files(std::string fileFolderPath, std::string fileExtension, std::vector<std::string>& file)
{
    std::string fileFolder = fileFolderPath + "\\*" + fileExtension;
    std::string fileName;
    struct _finddata_t fileInfo;
    long long findResult = _findfirst(fileFolder.c_str(), &fileInfo);
    if (findResult == -1)
    {
        _findclose(findResult);
        return 0;
    }
    bool flag = 0;



    do
    {
        fileName = fileFolderPath + "\\" + fileInfo.name;
        if (fileInfo.attrib == _A_ARCH)
        {
            file.push_back(fileName);
        }
    } while (_findnext(findResult, &fileInfo) == 0);



    _findclose(findResult);
}



int main()
{
    //Folder Path
    std::string fileFolderPath = "D:";




    std::cout << "Output all files in jpeg/JPEG format in the current directory" << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::string> jpeg_files;
    std::string fileExtension_jpeg = ".jpeg";
    get_files(fileFolderPath, fileExtension_jpeg, jpeg_files);



    for (int i = 0; i < jpeg_files.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << jpeg_files[i] << std::endl;
    }



    std::cout << "\nOutput all files in jpg/JPG format in the current directory" << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::string> jpg_files;
    std::string fileExtension_jpg = ".jpg";
    get_files(fileFolderPath, fileExtension_jpg, jpg_files);



    for (int i = 0; i < jpg_files.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << jpg_files[i] << std::endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

You can get the filtered file path and file name.And then you can try to use [CopyFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile)
 to copy the file.

Comment: Yours will most definitely work but I've solved the problem already. Thank you!